# What is this manga where a girl is told that she's never been seen only as a friend?

Tags: houkago-x-ponytail

[image]

This picture is really cute so I want to know what manga this is so please help me thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 6):

The manga that this image is from is called [**Houkago x Ponytail**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/43789/Houkago_x_Ponytail). It is in the second chapter and in page 29. A quick Google search will show this as the source, although you may need to dig a bit deeper.